# SQL statement to get the most frequent hours and/or period for a user

Tags: sql, datetime, period, hour

I'm new to SQL Datetime.

Considering I have records in MySQL with Datetime data (as seen below),
what is the best way to get the most frequent occurring HOUR or range/period for these records for a particular user (i.e. john)?

```
ID      | Datetime            | User      | Activity
0    2010-03-29 13:15:56        john         visit
1    2010-03-29 13:13:14        ariel        visit
2    2010-03-29 13:09:13        john         visit
3    2010-03-29 13:07:21        john         visit
4    2010-02-23 12:21:03        john         visit
5    2010-02-23 12:01:03        john         visit
6    2010-02-23 11:01:03        john         visit
7    2010-02-23 02:01:03        john         visit
```

With the above data,
the frequent hour for *john* doing *visit* would be *13*, while period would be *perhaps 12-13*.

**The goal is to find the period/time that the user does a certain activity most.**

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: none atm - you think I should start looking into it?

Comment: the answer I posted will word on most popular RDBMS, but you have to choose the right function which may be different if you're not using oracle

Comment: haha ok that was dumb, it's MySQL. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can depend on the database you're using, but in mysql :

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as count, HOUR(Datetime) as hour FROM table GROUP BY hour ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 1
```

(see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

with oracle you can write something like

```
select TO_CHAR(Datetime, 'HH24'), count(ID) from Table group by TO_CHAR(Datetime, 'HH24')
```

on other RDBMS use equivalent function to extract hour part from Datetime field.